# ng-grid cell edit enables even disabled from code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, internet-explorer, ng-grid

I have an ng-grid with some dynamic columns. 
And data binding and other functions of the grid are working well. 
I'm having conditional statement in my template to display a label or a textbox   according to conditions .

The problem is

In chorme..
The label is displaying correctly 
as shown in below

[image]

But when I double click the cell it goes to the cell editing mode as below

[image]

In IE 11

The same thing happens for the label and for textboxes when I type something it goes to cell edit mode and bounded events are not firing for those textboxes.
I've directives for validations to only allow numbers etc .. those things also not working.

[image]

But in chrome, if I don't double click a cell with a textbox it won't go to cell edit mode and everything works well.

Here is my code for dynamically define grid columns.

```
function prepareGridColumns() {

                var dtLength = $scope.dateList.length;
                $scope.columnDefinitions.length = 0;
                $scope.columnDefinitions = [
                    {
                        field: 'Item',
                        displayName: 'Item',
                        width: '25%'
                    },
                     {
                         field: 'SupplierName',
                         displayName: 'Supplier',
                         width: '15%'
                     },
                    {
                        field: 'Total',
                        displayName: 'Total',
                        width: '6%'
                    },
                        {
                            field: 'Variance',
                            displayName: 'Variance',
                            width: '6%'
                        }


                ];

                var colWidth = 0;
                if (dtLength > 0)
                    colWidth = 50 / dtLength;
                //var cWidth = colWidth.toString() + "%";

                for (var i = 0; i < dtLength; i++) {

                    var newcol = {
                        field: $scope.dateList[i].field,
                        displayName: $scope.dateList[i].displayName,
                        cellTemplate:
                            '<div class="ngCellText" >  <input type="text" ng-if="!controlGridCol(row.entity)" only-number decimal-upto="4"  data-ng-model="row.entity.' +
                                $scope.dateList[i].field +
                                '" class="form-control input-lg" ng-keyup="calculateForward(row.entity,col.field,row.entity.' +
                                $scope.dateList[i].field +
                                ')" ng-disabled="controlGridCol(row.entity)" ng-readonly="controlGridCol(row.entity)">' +
                                '<label ng-if="controlGridCol(row.entity)"  data-ng-bind="row.entity.' +
                                $scope.dateList[i].field +
                                '"></label></div>',
                        width: '60px',
                        enableCellEdit: true

                    }; // '<div class="ngCellText">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div>' 
                    $scope.columnDefinitions.push(newcol);

                }

                if (!$scope.$$phase)
                    $scope.$apply();

            };
```

Here is the code for grid

```
$scope.tGrid = {
                data: 'gridDataList',
                multiSelect: false,

                enableCellEdit: false,
                enableColumnResize: true,
                enableCellSelection: true,


                plugins: [new ngGridFlexibleHeightPlugin()],

                rowTemplate: '<div  style="height: 100%" ng-class="colorRow(row.getProperty(\'Variance\'))"><div ng-style="{ \'cursor\': row.cursor }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell ">' +
                    '<div class="ngVerticalBar" ng-style="{height: rowHeight}" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }"> </div>' +
                    '<div ng-cell></div>' +
                    '</div></div>',
                columnDefs: 'columnDefinitions',
                //enablePaging: true,
                showFooter: true,
                rowHeight: 40,

                footerTemplate: "<div ng-show=\"showFooter\" class=\"ngFooterPanel\" ng-class=\"{'ui-widget-content': jqueryUITheme, 'ui-corner-bottom': jqueryUITheme}\" ng-style=\"footerStyle()\">" +
                    "    <div class=\"ngTotalSelectContainer\" >" +
                    "        <div class=\"ngFooterTotalItems\" ng-class=\"{'ngNoMultiSelect': !multiSelect}\" >" +
                    "            <span class=\"ngLabel\">{{i18n.ngTotalItemsLabel}} {{maxRows()}}</span><span ng-show=\"filterText.length > 0\" class=\"ngLabel\">({{i18n.ngShowingItemsLabel}} {{totalFilteredItemsLength()}})</span>" +
                    "        </div>" +
                    "        <div class=\"ngFooterSelectedItems\" ng-show=\"multiSelect\">" +
                    "            <span class=\"ngLabel\">{{i18n.ngSelectedItemsLabel}} {{selectedItems.length}}</span>" +
                    "        </div>" +
                    "    </div>" +
                    "</div>"
            };
```

Comment: please post demo in plunker with your issue. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was.. 
Even I've mentioned  `enableCellEdit: false` in my grid declaration, I've set it to true in my dynamic column generation.

```
 var newcol = {
                        field: $scope.dateList[i].field,
                        displayName: $scope.dateList[i].displayName,
                        cellTemplate:
                            '<div class="ngCellText" >  <input type="text" ng-if="!controlGridCol(row.entity)" only-number decimal-upto="4"  data-ng-model="row.entity.' +
                                $scope.dateList[i].field +
                                '" class="form-control input-lg" ng-keyup="calculateForward(row.entity,col.field,row.entity.' +
                                $scope.dateList[i].field +
                                ')" ng-disabled="controlGridCol(row.entity)" ng-readonly="controlGridCol(row.entity)">' +
                                '<label ng-if="controlGridCol(row.entity)"  data-ng-bind="row.entity.' +
                                $scope.dateList[i].field +
                                '"></label></div>',
                        width: '60px',
                         enableCellEdit: true  // I've declared column with 
                                               // Cell Edit enabled

                    };
```

Actually this was my mistake..